# Creating a variable that indicates type of household - subsetting, conditional selection, data wrangling-Closed

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements, subset

I am analyzing a dataset with specific demographic information. These are the primary variables I am trying to wrangle and subset:

```
hh_id   is_head_of_household    married   gender   age
1          1                    single    male     28
1          0                    single    female   27
2          1                    married   male     33
2          0                    married   female   34
2          1                    single    male     6
```

I need to create a variable that indicates the type of household under these four specific categories: "single male head of household", "single female household", "married couple", "unmarried couple"

For example, each household has a unique ID and the first household represents an unmarried couple because there are **at least** two adults (18 and over) and **at least** one of them is head of household (1 or 0) and are both listed as "single" under the married column.
The second household is a married couple because there are **at least** two adults, one of them is the head, and are listed as "married" under the married column. 
A "single male" or "single female" household would have AT MOST one male or female adult that's also the head of household. Any other individuals within the household would have to be kids (under 18).

I tried creating a column that would indicate one of these four categories for EACH UNIQUE household id using dplyr:

First, I created an adult or child category:

```
individual_data["adult"] <- NA
individual_data$adult <- ifelse(individual_data$age >= 18, "adult", 
"child")
```

This is the code I have so far for trying to create a variable for single households:

```
individual_data["if_adult"] <- ifelse(individual_data$age >= 18, "1","0")
library(dplyr)
individual_data %>% 
group_by(hh_id) %>% 
mutate(unmarried_couple = sum(if_adult*(married =="Single"))==1,
total_adults = sum(if_adult))
```

This code does not yield the expected results and I'm unsure how to go about producing the other two categories. Ideally, my new dataset would look like this:

```
   hh_id   is_head_of_household    married   gender   age     type
   1          1                    single    male     28  unmarried couple
   1          0                    single    female   27  unmarried couple
   2          1                    married   male     33    married couple
   2          0                    married   female   34    married couple
   2          1                    single    male     6     married couple
   ..
   n          ----------------------------------------------------------
```

There should only be ONE categorization for EACH hh_id. How can I find a solution to this in dplyr?

data structure:

```
structure(list(hh_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L), person_id = 1:10, is_head_of_household = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), married = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Married", "Single"), class = "factor"), 
gender = structure(c(2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
2L), .Label = c("F", "Female", "FEMALE", "M", "Male", "MALE"
), class = "factor"), race = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Asian", "Black", "White"
), class = "factor"), age = c(28L, 27L, 34L, 33L, 6L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 3L, 30L), voted_in_2012 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), is_college_graduate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), adult = c("adult", "adult", 
"adult", "adult", "child", "adult", "adult", "adult", "child", 
"adult")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is "head of household" a synonym for "male" here? If so, can it be removed? It does not appear to be imparting any additional information. (It may just be that your data implies that accidentally - can a female be a head of a single or married household?).

Comment: both females and males can be head of a single or married household

Comment: Right, thanks - it looked redundant from the data.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: converted `married` to lowercase in `case_when` to capture situations where that variable is capitalized differently than sample data.

```
library(dplyr)
hh_types <- individual_data %>%
  filter(age >= 18) %>%  # only concerned with adults for categorization
  arrange(hh_id, -is_head_of_household) %>%   # bring head of hh to top
  group_by(hh_id) %>%              # For each hh_id...
  mutate(adult_count = n()) %>%    # ... how many adults
  slice(1) %>%                     # just keep the top row  (the head)
  ungroup() %>%

  mutate(category = case_when(
    tolower(married) == "married"   & adult_count > 1 ~ "married couple",
    tolower(married) == "single" & adult_count > 1 ~ "unmarried couple",
    adult_count == 1   ~ paste("single", gender, "head of household"),
    TRUE   ~  "Other")) %>%
  select(hh_id, category)


individual_data %>%
  left_join(hh_types)
#Joining, by = "hh_id"
#  hh_id is_head_of_household married gender age                        category
#1     1                    1  single   male  28                unmarried couple
#2     1                    0  single female  27                unmarried couple
#3     2                    1 married   male  33                  married couple
#4     2                    0 married female  34                  married couple
#5     2                    1  single   male   6                  married couple
#6     3                    1  single female  30 single female head of household
#7     4                    1  single   male  28   single male head of household
```

---

Sample data with single hh's added:

```
individual_data <- read.table(
  header = T,
  stringsAsFactors = F, 
  colClasses = c("integer", "integer", "character", "character", "integer"),
  text = "hh_id   is_head_of_household    married   gender   age
1          1                    single    male     28
1          0                    single    female   27
2          1                    married   male     33
2          0                    married   female   34
2          1                    single    male     6
3          1                    single    female   30
4          1                    single    male     28"
)
```

Comment: Your code almost worked but for unmarried and married couples, the category came out to "other" instead. It successfully categorized the single households. Am I implementing i wrongly somehow?

Comment: Could you share the rows from one `hh_id` that is getting categorized that way? I would expect they're getting characterized that way either because there are not two adults in that `hh_id` or else their `married` status is neither `single` nor `married`. Or something else I'm not seeing right now.

Comment: I made the necessary edits to your dataframe under category. As you can see, the first two households are coming out as "other."

Comment: When I load the sample data I included, then run my answer, I get the output I provided. 1) When you do that, do you get "other" for the first two households? 2) What version of `dplyr` are you using? I wouldn't think there would be breaking changes lately in the code I wrote that would make it run differently for you, but I don't know what else would do it...

Comment: There should only be ONE category for EACH hh_id, which I believe you did. I'm not sure how to replicate the sample data, but I noticed you had characters so I changed all my factors into characters for gender and married vars. Still ran into the same issue. I am using version 0.7.6

Comment: Aha, I thought you had that issue using my sample data. Could you pls amend your question to show a sample of the data you're working with? The most helpful thing would be to copy in as code the output of running `dput(head(your_data, 10))` -- that will show 10 rows of your data, plus the formats in which that data is stored, which will bear on how we should process it...

Comment: I updated my question to show the output of that code. It's the original data without any of the dplyr changes. Let me know if you need me to revise or change it.

Comment: Aha! Your real data has Single and Married capitalized, unlike sample data provided. Updated my answer to address this.